# Bootstrap model dialogues in same page not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap 3 model dialogue with a jQuery datatable. If the first one open and close second only background faded without the dialogue and freezes. Even the mouse click won't work too.

My action links

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Get File ", "_ViewFIles", "POPM_Trn_Job", null, new { @class = "modal-link btn btn-success" })
  @Html.ActionLink("Get Shared ", "GetSharedWithMe", "POPM_Trn_Job", null, new { @class = "modal-link2 btn btn-success" })
```

My dialogs

```html
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
</div>


<div id="modal-container-Share" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery for the first

```
                   $(function () {

                   $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
                        $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

                  });


                  $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                        $('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                    });


                $('#modal-container').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                });

                 $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

Second function

```
                ` $(function () {
                 $('body').on('click', '.modal-link2', function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container-Share');
                 $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');

                 });

                 $('body').on('click', '.modal-close-btn', function () {
                 $('#modal-container-Share').modal('hide');
                 });

   $('#modal-container-Share').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
                  });

                  $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
                  return false;
                  });
                });
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try this,  http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/

Comment: Thanks but i have tried  before but only thing is i need to inject the partial view  as well.  action link does not support data target .

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The solution is easy - take the downvotes as a sign that people thought your post needed improvement, and apply some improvements to your next posts. I added some suggestions under your answer. In relation to my comment above, please read the link - the community is firmly of the view that begging and pleading to volunteers is not reasonable. No question is more important than another here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. My script document section filled with three jQuery references; removing them fixed the issue. I guess because each of the partial views carried references and the main page also had a reference because each view had to use jQuery datatables.

Comment: Readers will appreciate that you have taken the time to self-answer. However, this site is not a chat-room: please take the time to use upper-case letters, and to use real words rather than abbreviated txt-spk, and to spell-check your work. We want posts to be as readable as possible here. Thanks!